# Can I find a closed form solution for this system of equation?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to find a closed form solution $(x_0,y_0,v_x,v_y)$ for the following equation, where $a$ and $M(t)$ are known numerically.

$$ 
\frac{v_x(x_0+tv_x+a)+v_y(y_0+v_yt)}{\sqrt{(x_0+v_xt+a)^2+(y_0+v_yt)^2}}+
\frac{v_x(x_0+tv_x-a)+v_y(y_0+v_yt)}{\sqrt{(x_0+v_xt-a)^2+(y_0+v_yt)^2}}
=M(t)
\tag1$$

Optimization using gradient descent doesn't yield good results because initilization is realy tedious. Grid search is out of question as I am looking for a fast solution.

It is proved that considering a noise-free measure $M(t)$ and at least $4$ measurments $M(t_1),M(t_2),M(t_3),M(t_4)$ the system will admit $4$ solutions and only one if we resctrict $(x_0,y_0)$ to the first quadrant of the real plane $\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^+$

I would like to solve the system of equations formed by the $4$ equations at $t=t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4$. A closed form solution would be nice but an approximation may suits well.

This feels like it would be accessible with some algebraic geometry dark magic, but my background isn't strong enough to solve this.

Some insights :

- Having only one measurment $M(t)$ and if we set $v_x,v_y$ the locus
  of $x_0,y_0$ is an hyperbolae
- Writting 
  $$
  r_1(t)={\sqrt{(x_0+v_xt+a)^2+(y_0+v_yt)^2}}$$
  $$r_2(t)={\sqrt{(x_0+v_xt-a)^2+(y_0+v_yt)^2}}
  $$
  We have :
  $$M(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(r_1(t)+r_2(t))$$
- Writting $$x(t)=x_0+v_xt$$ $$y(t)=y_0+y_xt$$

  At each time step $t$, solving for $(x,y)$ $$r_1(t)+r_2(t)=2C$$ Yields
  an ellipse with foci $(-a,0)$ and $(a,0)$ and semi-major axis of
  length $C$.

Comment: Your eq.1 has the form, $$\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}}+\frac{A}{\sqrt{B}} = M(t)$$ This is easily simplified, or is there a typo in the subscripts somewhere?

Comment: There was a typo with the sign of $a$ in the two terms. I've corrected it. thanks

Comment: Oh, ok. By the way, did you see my answer to your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182564/)?

Comment: Yes, it looks realy nice, I am working on it at the moment, but with my poor bagage in math, it may takes a bit of time :). As soon as I've understood it and managed to make the needed conclusion, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: One additional insight on the question above : Having only one measurment $M(t)$ and if we set $v_x,v_y$ the locus of $x_0,y_0$ is an hyperbolae. I can give more details but it is cumbersome.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, if you are still interessed in this problem, or still want to help me :) I've stated this problem in another way in another question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195661/advice-to-solve-a-system-of-8th-order-univariate-polynomials

Comment: Gradient descent can be a very poor choice of the objective function is not convex and nearly rotational symmetric. There are some notorious counter-examples like the Rosenbrock function or paraboloids with tight elliptical level sets. Try some conjugate gradient variant or BFGS.

Comment: @LutzL I've tried to optimize this problem with the full analytic hessian, without success. The two methods you gave just try to give a better approximation of the hessian that gauss-newton, right ? In the case that the local minima I end up converging in are due to some local flatness / rotational symetry, wouldn't it have been solved by the use of the true hessian ?

Comment: Yes, the full exact Hessian trumps the approximations. Then you are back to the failure scenarios of Newton's method. Did you employ a line-search with it?

Comment: Yes, line search in the gradient's direction, levenberg for ill-conditioned hessian. In my opinion the problem realy come from that we need a good initial guess.