# Analytic solution of a system of four second order polynomials

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Can I systematically solve in $\mathbb{R}^4$ the following system without using Grobner basis algorithm ?
If not, can I find the exact number of solutions ?

$$
\begin{equation*}
   \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
X_1^2+X_2^2=a\\
X_1X_3+X_2X_4=b\\
X_3^2+X_4^2+eX_1+fX_2=c\\
eX_3+fX_4=d
      \end{aligned}
   \right.
\end{equation*}
$$

$a,b,c,d,e,f$ are known reals constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use *[resultants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Resultant.html)*. Given two equations of degrees $k_1, k_2$,

$$F_1(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m) = 0$$

$$F_2(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) = 0$$

the resultant can eliminate one variable between them. By applying it repeatedly to a system, you can reduce it to just one equation. (It is computationally expensive, but if the degrees $k_i$ of your equations are small enough, then it is feasible.)

For your system, I find one can resolve it into a *sextic* in $x_4$. (I used *Mathematica*). Thus, in general, you have ***six*** solutions. However, the transformation,

$$x_4 = \frac{ez+df}{e^2+f^2}$$

simplifies it to the form,

$$z^6+c_1z^4+c_2z^2+c_3=0$$

so the sextic has a solvable Galois group and your $x_i$ in fact can be expressed in radicals.

Comment: The command in Mathematica is, for example, $Resultant[x^2+y^2-z^2,x^3+y^3+z^3,z]$ which eliminates the variable $z$. You can also use the ***Eliminate*** command [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eliminate%5B%7Bx1%5E2+%2B+x2%5E2+%3D%3D+a%2C+x1+x3+%2B+x2+x4+%3D%3D+b%2C+x3%5E2+%2B+x4%5E2+%2B+e+x1+%2B+f+x2+%3D%3D+c%2C+e+x3+%2B+f+x4+%3D%3D+d%7D%2C+%7Bx1%2C+x2%2C+x3%7D%5D).

Comment: The transformation worked wonders

Comment: @AntoineBassoul: What is the background of this problem? A system of non-linear equations is not always solvable in radicals, so I'm curious why it is so in this particular case.

Comment: We're trying to estimate the kinematic parameter $x(t=t_0),y(t=t_0),v_x,v_y$ of a target with a rectilinear uniform motion (MRU) in the plane. We're measuring the distance between the target and an observer which is manoeuvring (think of boats), the observer's manoeuver is known. If the observer doesn't move, you can't estimate the target's motion only from distance measurements, same problem if the observer is in MRU. It is however observable if the observer has a uniformly accelerated trajectory. In fact in the above equations $e$ and $f$ are the x and y coordinate of the acceleration vecto

Comment: And you have noticed that if the acceleration's modulus is null then we can't solve the above system. Which is very desirable ;). You may want to try googling "target motion analysis". On a mathematical point of view, I can't go into details, but it is related with the intersection of n circles. Additionaly, my other unanswered question is a similirar problem, but with doppler measurments, one target, one emiter and one receiver.

Comment: @AntoineBassoul: Thank you for the details. I've looked at your other question. Unfortunately, it's much, much harder to find an analytic solution for it.

Comment: How did you find the transformation to simplify the polynomial ? Is this mathematician intuition or did you asked mathematica ?

Comment: @AntoineBassoul: Originally, I solved for $x_1$. It yielded a sextic with a solvable Galois group but _Mathematica_ couldn't express the roots in radicals. Upon testing the other $x_i$ , I found it could do so for $x_4$ and had the form $x_4 = c+\sqrt{\text{cubic root}}$ with some constant $c$. I then knew that a rational transformation would eliminate the $x^n$ coefficients with odd $n$.